# OpenGL: How to darken a sprite in Cocos2d

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I've tried shooting the dark with all the GL functions, to no avail on what I'm sure has to be pretty simple.  I'm new to it.

I want to take a sprite and simply darken it.  My thoughts on this were to load the sprite, add a grey layer overtop  of it (using CCLayerColor with a grey color), apply some kind of GL function, and then grab the output and display it onscreen.  However, in every variant I tried where my source image was correctly darkened, the transparency around it was also affected, showing the grey.  I need the darkening effect to be masked to the shape of the source sprite.

Here's the code I have so far.  How can I correctly mask the darkening effect?

```
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName: mod.backgroundImagePath];
CCLayerColor* tint = [CCLayerColor node];
[tint setColor:ccc3(205, 205, 205)];
//[tint setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc){GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA}];  Need help here?
[sprite addChild:tint];

CCRenderTexture* rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:sprite.boundingBox.size.width height:sprite.boundingBox.size.height];
[rt begin];
[sprite visit];
[rt end];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set the [color](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/docs/api/Classes/CCNode.html#//api/name/color) property of `CCSprite` (which is inherited from `CCNode`):

```
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"foobar"];

sprite.color = [CCColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
```

Where the `r,g,b,a` variables are the color you want to use, normalized between 0 and 1.

I.e.:
Setting to `0,0,0,1` will make the object completely black.

Comment: It pains me that it is that easy.  Any chance you can explain why applying a color to a sprite's texture works here as part of your answer?

Comment: @GregoryJohnson So, did it work as you expected? The `color` parameter is the color that gets modulated with the texture color in the underlaying OpenGL shader. If you look into the source code, there will be a line somewhere in a GLSL shader where they do something like: `texture2D(CC_texture) * color`;

Comment: yes, it worked exactly as expected.  It is painful because I spent too long playing with GL stuff when it's just one line of code.  Thanks for the extra detail.